Access problem for specific endpoint
I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't access Azure VDI endpoint https://client.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html with browser or curl. I was getting 403 Site Disabled error on http level. I can access the url with mobile or other windows machine. I tried below scenarios but there was no chance.

I tried different curl/opensll versions.
I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04.1 (latest LTS).
I tried different network
MAC address change
I made test in a docker node.
I tested with ArchLinux in VM (NAT Mode)

Below scenarios are working:

Using ArchLinux in VM (Bridge Mode)
Using live Ubuntu 20.04.1 in VM (Bridge Mode)

I assume that my Ubuntu has problem in network layer. Bu I am not sure how can I found it and fix.
I just founded below differences between working machine curl verbose log:



Not working
Working




TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):


SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384


ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1




Ubuntu 20.04.1 is in no way the latest version. You may want to review your question and correct as needed.

I wrote "latest LTS" not "latest".

The latest LTS release is currently Ubuntu 24.04, not 20.04. Arch worked in the VM leads me to speculate that Ubuntu 24.04 will most likely work in a VM too. If so, minus the VM there's your solution.
